# Thackeray's scavenger hunt

Tags: guild-wars

I'm trying to complete this quest, http://wiki.guildwars.com/wiki/Thackeray%27s_scavenger_hunt but I am struggling. So far I have delivered the candles, the cupcake, and 3 dwarven ales, along with the kabob.

Still the only dialog options I have when I speak to him are `'Backup a second a plan?'` and `'I've got a drink here I think you'll really enjoy'` to which I have donated 3 dwarven ales I bought on Embark Beach.

What else do I need to do to be able to progress with this quest and finish this segment of the Guild Wars Live content?

I had received some sacks of junk from him which I opened, along with the wrapped present.

**Update**
As you can see from these images, I do not have any other dialog options than those I included in my question.

I have also got, as you can see from the second picture, 3 rice wines, 2 dwarven ales, and a keg of ale. None of which he will accept. He doesn't even recognise that I have the dwarven ale or rice wine in my inventory.

[image]
[image]

I have even approached him with all the drinks mentioned on the Wiki, to no avail.
[image]

**Update 2**
Upon further investigation, it looks like all my progress in this quest was lost when they changed it. I've so far handed in, 1 Birthday Cupcake, 1 Drake Kabob, and 3 Dwarven Ales. So I guess I need to go and refarm the Grawl Necklaces! Argh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have spent the last 5 hours farming `Stone Grawl Necklace` to get the honeycombs to make the candles. Handed the candles in and the quest completed as normal. So it looks like if you had done some of the quest before they updated it and then come back to it. Your progress will have been wiped!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Choose the option:

> Let's speed this up, shall we? What exactly do you want?"

He should give you a list of what you still need.

If you're still getting the donate drinks dialogue option, then it is possible that the drinks didn't take. Did you double check that they were taken from your inventory? On the talk page, there are reports of other people who have had trouble with this mission's alcohol requirement.

Comment: This dialog option just lists what he wants generally, such as 'something sweet' a 'meal' a 'drink' etc. It doesn't seem to be a dynamic list